# Wordpress запрет коротких ссылок

Tags: wordpress, redirect

Доброго всем времени суток.
Есть у меня одно ТЗ написанное СЕО-специалистами по улучшению сайта. Все бы ничего, но в одном пункте указано что короткие ссылки типа http://site.ru/?p=88 отдают 301 редирект на нормальный URL и это говорят плохо для поисковиков.
Я конечно понимаю что это бред, но все же хотелось бы узнать, возможно есть какой то способ при вводе такой короткой ссылки отдавать 404 ошибку. Ведь при вводе несуществующей короткой ссылки именно 404 ошибку и выдает.

Comment: Лучше не потакать бредням недосеошникам, а донести до заказчика что это наоборот - лучше.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Один из вариантов прописать ответ 404 в `functions.php`

```php
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'error_redirect', 5 );
function error_redirect() {
    if ( isset( $_GET ) && array_key_exists( 'p', $_GET ) ) {
        global $wp_query;
        $wp_query->set_404();
        status_header( 404 );
        get_template_part( 404 );
        exit();
    }
}
```